# Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: PBF error: invalid BlobHeader size (> max_blob_header_size)

Tags: postgresql

I am using a docker project in a rather strong server(120GB RAM and plenty of disc space).

When trying to run an import on postgres server I get the following error

```
Using projection SRS 4326 (Latlong)
NOTICE:  table "place" does not exist, skipping
Allocating memory for dense node cache
Allocating dense node cache in one big chunk
Allocating memory for sparse node cache
Sharing dense sparse
Node-cache: cache=1207MB, maxblocks=154496*8192, allocation method=11
Mid: pgsql, scale=10000000 cache=1207
Setting up table: planet_osm_nodes
Setting up table: planet_osm_ways
Setting up table: planet_osm_rels

Reading in file: /app/src/data.osm.pbf
Using PBF parser.
node cache: stored: 0(-nan%), storage efficiency: -nan% (dense blocks: 0, sparse nodes: 0), hit rate: -nan%
Osm2pgsql failed due to ERROR: PBF error: invalid BlobHeader size (> max_blob_header_size)
ERROR: Error executing external command: /app/src/osm2pgsql/osm2pgsql -lsc -O gazetteer --hstore --number-processes 1 -C 1207 -P 5432 -d nominatim /app/src/data.osm.pbf
```

How could I increase the max_blob_header_size?

Comment: How was the PBF file created?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon the same issue while feeding an S3 hosted PBF file into a  Nominatim docker container.

Unfortunately I failed to configure the access to the PBF file properly so the docker container saved the XML error response as /app/src/data.osm.pbf. That's why the file header check fails.